# how many concurrent user can login to silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, web-applications

I am newbie in silver light. 
Can any one tell me how many concurrent users can have in silverlight application?
ANd also what happes to the aplication if we have more than 500 concurrent users?

Regards
Chinnayya

Answer (score 5):

The answer is 1.

A silverlight application is run on the client by the one user.

Typically though a Line of business app will have a server backend that the Silverlight application will talk to via WCF.  That backend server can support thousands of users.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scaling question.

The answer will depend heavily on the Server HW, but even more on the Application-Design.

The naive answer is: *Your application will be slower.*

Unfortunately only trial and error will show you (exactly) how much slower ..